# How to make a non-float subfigure environment?

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I am writing a document class `report` that has a maximum page limit. I tend to stay away from float environments for tables and figures since I like to have them where I code them in (I try `[h]`, and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).
For example, for figures I usually do this:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figure.png}
  \captionof{figure}{caption}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{center}
```

But I have to make a subfigure for some of my report's pictures. Here is the code for the subfigure:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1.png}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure2.png}
    \caption{figure2 caption}
    \label{fig:figure2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{figures}
  \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to convert this into a non float environment or some package to ensure it will be always where I code it in?

Comment: I suppose, as long it inside a `figure` environment it will float anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: You can use the `H` option (from the `float` package). If the figure doesn't float anymore, I can't see why the subfigures would.

Answer (score 2):

One option using `minipage`s and `\captionof` from the `caption` package, loaded via the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure1.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure2.png} 
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption} 
  \label{fig:figure2} 
\end{minipage} 
\captionof{figure}{figures} 
\label{fig:figures} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment, a 2x2 grid was requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure1.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure2.png} 
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption} 
  \label{fig:figure2} 
\end{minipage}\par
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure1.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption}
  \label{fig:figure3}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{figure2.png} 
  \captionof{subfigure}{caption} 
  \label{fig:figure4} 
\end{minipage} 
\captionof{figure}{figures} 
\label{fig:figures} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Thanks for the big help! Is there a way to modify the above so that it will be a 2x2 grid for 4 figures - but same size as these two?

Comment: @SmittyShultz You're welcome! Please see my updated answer for the grid code.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work anymore with miktex 22.3 (2022.5.25). I'm looking for exactly the same task. Anyone could help ?